# DRF model Predictions using H2O and scoring

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, h2o

My goal is to create a DRF model in H2O with the TRAIN, VALIDATION and TEST datasets I have and predict the RMSE, R2, MSE etc on the TEST model.

Below is the piece of code:

```
DRFParameters rfParms = (DRFParameters) algParameter;
rfParms._response_column = trainDataFrame._names[responseColumn(trainDataFrame)]; //The response column 

rfParms._train = trainDataFrame._key;
//rfParms._valid = testDataFrame._key;
rfParms._nfolds = 5;
DRF job = new DRF(rfParms);
DRFModel drf = job.trainModel().get(); // Train the model
Frame pred = drf.score(testDataFrame); //Score the test
```

Here I don't know how to proceed with in finding the predictions (R2, RMSE, MSE, MAE etc) after scoring.

Could you please help in H2O DRF modeling and predictions calculation using JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your model is a regression, binomial or multinomial model you'll have to use one of `ModelMetricsRegression.make()`, `ModelMetricsBinomial.make()` or `ModelMetricsMultinomial.make()`. They have slightly different signatures - you can find them in our Java docs.

For the `trainDataFrame` you can get them from your `drf` model, it's in `drf._output._training_metrics` (you might need to cast it to an appropriate type as this one is a generic `ModelMetrics`). If you use your test dataset as a validation frame you can get the metrics from `drf._output._validation_metrics`.

@Edit:

```
DRFModel drf = job.trainModel().get(); // Train the model
Frame pred = drf.score(testDataFrame); //Score the test
ModelMetricsBinomial mm = ModelMetricsBinomial.make(preds.vec(2), trainDataFrame.vec(rfParms._response_column));
double auc = mm.auc();
double rmse = mm.rmse();
double r2 = mm.r2();
// etc.
```

Comment: Could you please brief it for the binomial one?
I need R2 RMSE etc from the 'pred'   ((Frame pred = drf.score(testDataFrame); //Score the test))
Also I need to find the deviation of test frame from the model.
Would you mind giving a code example as well?

Comment: @RejoyMathew see edit, should work but didn't run it myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the speedy response.

Comment: I have one more question:
After the training and scoring of model how do i find the feature important variables (in JAVA)?